# Session system in bubble - database and UI

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, web

I’m a new bubble developer and I would like to know how we can create the session in PHP, but on bubble.is. I would like to know the following:

**How we can recover all data  to a user when and he log in to his account ?**

Moreover, I want to know **how we can change to a user’s account and not to the other ?**

For example, when User1 makes an update to his account, this change will only be applied to his account and not change the data of the User2. User2 won’t access data changed by User1 because it affected only User1's account. So when User1 logs in to his account, he will find all his proper data (default data and data changed) while when User2 logs in to his account he can’t find the data changed by User1 because it is supposed to be applied only to User1's account.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: I've no code, bubble is plateforme where you can make apps without any code ! If you to see it, you can go to this link : bubble.is

Answer (score 0):

You'll have trouble implementing this using PHP.

Bubble apps come with a User object already created in the Bubble database. Use this User and add any fields you might need to add to it (e.g. Reputation as a number, like in Stack Overflow).

Here's a workflow that does what you're looking for: [image: Bubble workflow to edit a User's First Name]

This workflow will save an input's value to the User's "First" field. The workflow is triggered by clicking a button.

For more general info about starting on Bubble, I suggest you check out the free [Bubble tutorials](https://bubble.is/lessons) related to saving data or the [ZeroQode Labs tutorials](https://lab.zeroqode.com/course/bubble-for-beginners-course-1549860685047x857418658238693400), of which there is one free one. There are a some other tutorials online but most of them aren't free.